# Jenkins added Links to Dashboard not working

Tags: security, jenkins, dashboard

I published a html report and display it via iframe in the Jenkins Dashboard. It looks good, but I cannot open the links to the subpages in there by left-clicking on them. They work though if I open them in a new tab.

I found the [security policy page](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy) and tried to unset the header using this command in the Jenkins script console:

```
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "")
```

but the links still don't work. Another link to a latest test page works. Is there another configuration that I am missing?

I also added two links to the Dashboard with the Rich Text Plugin. One linking to a latestTest Jenkins page is working. Another one linking to a local html File (with  `file://///` ...) doesn't work either and shows the same behavior that opening it in a new tab works fine.

Comment: Suddenly the links from the published html work. I think this is probably because I republished them. I thought changing the security option has an effect on previously published links but maybe it does not. Unfortunately the link to the local html file in the Rich Text box still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Add switch -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP= to jenkins run command line.

```
java -Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP= -jar /app/jenkins.war
```

If you run from war file.

Comment: I set the CSP header via the Jenkins Skript-Konsole. Shouldn't that have immediate effects for testing? Anyways, I tried setting it in the run command line now and restartet. Still doesn't work :/

Comment: How you publish HTML?

Comment: In a pipeline script with: 

    publishHTML (target: [
          allowMissing: false,
          alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false,
          keepAll: true,
          reportDir: "$WORKSPACE/${targetfolder}/",
          reportFiles: 'Tests.html',
          reportName: "Test Result"
        ])

Comment: This is my: ```this.steps.publishHTML([allowMissing: false, alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false, keepAll: true, reportDir: 'report', reportFiles: 'mochawesome.html', reportName: "Tests Running  Report for Build ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}", reportTitles: ''])``` I'm not use workspace. I'm set report dir only. Try it.

Comment: Thank you but I don't think that is the reason. The page does get published. Also, the problem is not just with the published html, I also added a link to the Jenkins Dashboard via Rich Text Plugin to a local html file and that is a non-working link either. I'll add that info to my question.

Comment: Ok. Any way read docs: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/htmlpublisher/#-publishhtml-%20publish%20html%20reports